# How to get text string dimensions if I have CTFontRef?

Tags: ios

I know I can use: `CGSize R = [myString sizeWithFont:uiFont];`
But the problem is that I do not have UIFont, I use Core Text. So I have CTFontRef.
Any way to get the string size with the givet CTFontRef? I also have font size in `double`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `CTFramesetter` then use `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` to measure the dimensions of a string when rendered as text -- using the additional context you provide.

of course, you could create a function which reduces the variables to font+size from there.